# Partitioning taking so long on SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, time

It takes forever while resizing a partition by taking from another partition. I used to do it on my desktop PC and worked like a charm before. Now I have a laptop with SSD. It is taking forever to complete the partitioning. I use minitool partition wizard free version. Using the windows disk management also is taking time than it used to on my old PC. Please help.

Comment: resizing a partition is instantaneous, but resizing the filesystem inside it can take some time. What filesystem are we talking about, and how much are you expanding it by?

Comment: Post the SMART info of the SSD (using a utility such as [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy)). What model is it?

Comment: INTEL SSDPEKNW512GB. Would this do?

Comment: SMART statistics track the health of your harddisk. posting them will tell us if you are experiencing a hardware failure. SMART is probably more useful for Mechanical disks, but has some meaningful info on SSDs as well.

Comment: It shows 'SMART not supported' on speccy.